# ReferenceError: DOMRect is not defined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, undefined

1. jest config:
   testEnvironment: 'jsdom'
2. sample code:

   ```js
   it('test', async () => {
    await act(async () => {
      await asyncRender(
        <Popover isOpen position={new DOMRect(10, 10)}>
          <Button text="Child Button" />
        </Popover>
      );
    });

    expect(...);
   });
   ```
3. Get the error information， `ReferenceError: DOMRect is not defined`.

Anyone has any suggestions about this issue?

Comment: what is DOMRect supposed to be, where is it defined?

Comment: DOMRect is defined in the node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.dom.d.ts, and its declaration like this: interface DOMRect extends DOMRectReadOnly {
    height: number;
    width: number;
    x: number;
    y: number;
}. Here, it only a position variate with x and y coordinate.

Answer (score 6):

Issue is jsdom does not implement the DOMRect class.
If you check the source code you'll see it implements getClientBoundingRect by returning a plain object with properties like a DOMRect. But no class anywhere.

Solutions are

A) open a issue at jsdom repo and hope they'll add it

B) work around it by not using DOMRect at all:
In your example, passing a {x:10,y:10} object may work fine

C) create a custom DOMRect class within jest environment.
There are (said to be) various ways to do this.
What worked for me (jest 27+) was to create a file that provides a jsdom environment + a custom DOMRect mock:

```
const JsDomEnv = require('jest-environment-jsdom');

class CustomEnvironment extends JsDomEnv {

  async setup() {
    await super.setup();
    this.global.DOMRect = class DOMRect {
        bottom:number=0;
        left:number=0;
        right:number=0;
        top:number=0;
        constructor (public x=0, public y=0, public width=0, public height=0) {};
        static fromRect(other?: DOMRectInit): DOMRect {
            return new DOMRect(other.x,other.y,other.width,other.height)
        }
        toJSON() {
            return JSON.stringify(this)
        }
    }
  }

}

module.exports = CustomEnvironment;
```

and then pass the file path to jest config:
testEnvironment:'./custom-env.ts' instead of 'jsdom'.

Comment: For reference, the issues seems to exist since 2019: https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2716